# mpi4py memory leak when creating shared arrays

Tags: python, mpi, shared-memory, mpi4py

I have an application where I need to perform many loops, each of which will create a shared array that I want to overwrite the previously shared array.

When I try this, however, I run into what seems like a memory leak.

Minimal example to run with `mpirun -np 2 python example.py` :

```
from mpi4py import MPI 
import numpy as np 

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD 

for i in range(0,100000000):

    # create a shared array of some size of type double
    size = 100000 
    itemsize = MPI.DOUBLE.Get_size() 
    if comm.Get_rank() == 0: 
        nbytes = size * itemsize 
    else: 
        nbytes = 0

    
    # on rank 0, create the shared block
    # on rank 1 get a handle to it (known as a window in MPI speak)
    win = MPI.Win.Allocate_shared(nbytes, itemsize, comm=comm) 

    # create a numpy array whose data points to the shared mem
    buf, itemsize = win.Shared_query(0) 
    assert itemsize == MPI.DOUBLE.Get_size() 
    ary = np.ndarray(buffer=buf, dtype='d', shape=(size,))
```

This creates the shared array `ary`.
If you run this, you'll see that memory use is increasing.
The program might even crash.

I narrowed this down to the creation of the window, i.e. same is seen with this smaller loop:

```
from mpi4py import MPI 
import numpy as np 

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD 

for i in range(0,100000000):

    # create a shared array of some size of type double
    size = 100000 
    itemsize = MPI.DOUBLE.Get_size() 
    if comm.Get_rank() == 0: 
        nbytes = size * itemsize 
    else: 
        nbytes = 0

    win = MPI.Win.Allocate_shared(nbytes, itemsize, comm=comm)
```

So I tried placing a `win.Free()` after creating the window; this resulted in a smaller memory leak, but still noticeable in `top`.

Is there a proper way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

I simply want to loop over shared array creations, and hopefully deallocate the arrays if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a version problem. Use this script to measure a leak:

```
from mpi4py import MPI 
import numpy as np
import gc
import psutil

def rss():
    return psutil.Process().memory_info().rss
    

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD 

initial_memory = rss()
for i in range(0,1000000000):

    
    # create a shared array
    size = int(1e9)
    itemsize = MPI.DOUBLE.Get_size() 
    if comm.Get_rank() == 0: 
        nbytes = size * itemsize 
    else: 
        nbytes = 0

    # on rank 0, create the shared block
    # on rank 1 get a handle to it (known as a window in MPI speak)
    win = MPI.Win.Allocate_shared(nbytes, itemsize, comm=comm) 

    # create a numpy array whose data points to the shared mem
    buf, itemsize = win.Shared_query(0)
    assert itemsize == MPI.DOUBLE.Get_size() 
    ary = np.ndarray(buffer=buf, dtype='d', shape=(size,))

    win.Free()

    if comm.Get_rank() == 0:
        if i % 1000 == 0:
            print(f"{i} {rss()-initial_memory}")
```

On MacOS using Open MPI v2.0.4 I observe a definite increase in memory with iterations.

On Linux using Open MPI v3.1.6 I observe an initial jump (probably cache) then a flatline in memory; perfectly normal I think.

So I think this is simply a version issue.